# Do the exceptional root systems arise in the real world?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, applied-mathematics, applications, exceptional-groups

I am looking for a list of real world examples where the exceptional roots systems $E_6, E_7, E_8, F_4$, and $G_2$, and their associated Lie algebras and Lie groups, arise. To make this question a little less vague, I should indicate what I mean by "real world": First of all, in physics, I require that this be experimentally verifiable, so $G_2$ holonomies in stringy math should not count, nor should grand unified $E8$-theories. Industrial applications would be great, as would examples from biology.

Comment: Do uses of the E8 *lattice* in error-resistant communications count?

Comment: That sounds very interesting! So yes!

Comment: The alcoves of the affine $G_2$ root system give a highly symmetric tiling of the plane by congruent triangles. I would be amazed if this picture didn't appear somewhere "in the real world."

Comment: [Baez and Huerta - $G_2$ and the rolling ball](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2447).

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by the “real world”, but whatever it is math is part of it.

Comment: @AndyPutman: I tried to define "real world" in the question.

Comment: @AndyPutman How many times have I heard a mathematician say "I have no idea what you mean by X," or slight variations of it, where X is just a perfectly plain concept understandable by everyone. Typically they are pretty smug about it, too. But if you really want a fruitful conversation with someone, you should at least attempt to construct a generous interpretation of what the other person says.

Comment: @R.P.: In light of the thousands of years of philosophical reflection on the subject, I don't think the nature of the "real world" as it relates to mathematics is a "perfectly plain concept understandable by everyone". Being some kind of Platonist, I think that mathematical concepts are perfectly real and exist in the world. When my students ask me a question like that of the OP, I always interpret it as "When will me or someone like me need to know this?" and I answer accordingly, but on a website for professional mathematicians I think we can expect more rigor and precision in our language.

Comment: @AndyPutman Okay. Thank you for being kind enough to clarify your response. :)

Comment: $E_8$ appearing in an experiment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32315/has-the-lie-group-e8-really-been-detected-experimentally

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Noam Elkies alluded to in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/454263/do-the-exceptional-root-systems-arise-in-the-real-world#comment1175672_454263), the E8 lattice plays a role in coding theory, basically because it such an efficient sphere packing. For example, Kurkoski has proposed using it for error correction in flash memory: [The E8 Lattice and Error Correction in Multi-Level Flash Memory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.5764) (but I don't know if this error-correction scheme is actually used in practice).